# how inner join 2 tables display specific fields in datagridview with dapper in MS-ACCESS database in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, dapper

why "codeproduct" from the StocksoutDetail table does not appear in the datagridview is there something wrong with my code and also why in the datagridview another field appears even though I did not select the field in the SQL. Please Guide Me

Thanks

```
Public Class Form1
    Private sosservice As New StocksoutService()
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.DataSource = sosservice.GetStockOut()
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class StocksoutService
    Public Function GetOledbConnectionString() As String
        Return "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\dapperdemo.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    End Function
    Private ReadOnly _conn As OleDbConnection
    Private _connectionString As String = GetOledbConnectionString()
    Public Sub New()
        _conn = New OleDbConnection(_connectionString)
    End Sub
    Public Function GetStockOut() As IEnumerable(Of Stocksout)
        Dim sql = "SELECT Stocksout.Invno AS [Invno],StocksoutDetail.CodeProduct AS [CodeProduct] FROM Stocksout INNER JOIN StocksoutDetail ON Stocksout.Invno = StocksoutDetail.Invno"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of Stocksout)(sql).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
Public Class Stocksout
    Public Property Invno() As String
    Public Property HeaderInvno() As Integer
    Public Property CreatedBy() As String
    Public Property Created() As DateTime
    Public Property ModifiedBy() As String
    Public Property Modified() As DateTime
    Public Property StocksoutDetail() As New List(Of StocksoutDetail)()
End Class
Public Class StocksoutDetail
    Public Property Id() As Integer
    Public Property No() As Integer
    Public Property Invno() As String
    Public Property CodeProduct() As String
    Public Property Barcode() As String
    Public Property Colorcode() As String
    Public Property Size() As String
    Public Property Qty() As Integer
End Class
```

[image: result in datagridview]

Comment: Just because you query a few fields of the Stocksout object, data bind doesn't know what fields you want to hide or show. You have to do that yourself. When you bind to an object, it's going to show all the fields of that object, whether or not you load them with data from a database. I'd recommend you "flatten it out"... create a DTO object with properties of only the fields you want to display in the DGV, and load that up from the database, and bind a List(Of NewObject) to the DGV. NewObject can be a few fields from Stocksout and a few fields from StocksoutDetail, whatever you need.

Comment: Presumably there is a 1:M relationship between Stocksout and StocksoutDetail (ie.  One record in stocksout, many in stocksoutdetail), often in DVG terms called master/detail which probably can't be displayed nicely using the standard grid controls.  You may want to have a read over [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/creating-a-master-detail-form-using-two-datagridviews?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).  Alternatively, there are many 3rd party grid controls that do this. Or look at treeviews

Comment: @HardCode , Thank you for your reply. `I'd recommend you "flatten it out"... create a DTO object with properties of only the fields you want to display in the DGV` for this please guide me

Comment: @Hursey , Thank you for your reply, yes right you said but can still display using DataGridView without using third parties

Comment: @pret I should have said, create a DTO `class` (properties, no functions), with all the properties you want to see on the DGV. Then load an object instantiated from that class with the data from the database, and bind that object to the DGV.

Answer (score 1):

As per the guidelines and recommendations of @HardCode

```
  Private sosservice As New StocksoutService()
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.DataSource = sosservice.GetStockOut()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetStockOut() As IEnumerable(Of DTOStocksout)
        Dim sql = "SELECT Stocksout.Invno AS [Invno],StocksoutDetail.CodeProduct AS [CodeProduct] FROM Stocksout INNER JOIN StocksoutDetail ON Stocksout.Invno = StocksoutDetail.Invno"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of DTOStocksout)(sql).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function
Public Class DTOStocksout
    Public Property Invno() As String
    Public Property CodeProduct() As String

End Class
```